# django cms frontend editer display error

Tags: django, django-cms

Am trying to access the django cmcs frontend editor and after input the login details, i get the following error.

```
AttributeError at /en/

'NoneType' object has no attribute 'has_change_permission'

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://*.*.*.*:8000/en/
Django Version:     1.6.5
Exception Type:     AttributeError
Exception Value:    

'NoneType' object has no attribute 'has_change_permission'

Exception Location:     /home/bg/workspace/my-site/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cms/templatetags/cms_tags.py in get_processors, line 352
Python Executable:  /home/bg/workspace/my-site/env/bin/python
Python Version:     2.7.3
Python Path:    

['/home/bg/workspace/my-site',
 '/home/bg/workspace/my-site/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/distribute-0.6.24-py2.7.egg',
 '/home/bg/workspace/my-site/env/lib/python2.7',
 '/home/bg/workspace/my-site/env/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2',
 '/home/bg/workspace/my-site/env/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/home/bg/workspace/my-site/env/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/home/bg/workspace/my-site/env/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/home/bg/workspace/my-site/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages']
```

How can i fix it?

Comment: It would be very hard to guess your view code

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue with django-cms 3.0.4 / Python 3.4, it may be related to the djangocms-column plugin (version 1.4).

This problem appeared when editing a page; either with djangocms-installer default pages, as well as when creating a new page at trying to add the multi-columns plugin into it.

For a bit more details, the error is encountered when interpreting `{% render_plugin plugin %}`, in *multi_column.html* (line #4):

`In template /dvlpt/venv/my_project/lib/python3.4/site-packages/djangocms_column/templates/cms/plugins/multi_column.html, error at line 4
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'has_change_permission'`

More exactly, the AttributeError exception is raised by line #352 of cms/templatetags/cms_tags.py, in get_processors():

`if toolbar and toolbar.edit_mode and placeholder.has_change_permission(request) and getattr(placeholder, 'is_editable', True):
...`

I've posted a comment at djangocms-colum github : https://github.com/divio/djangocms-column/issues/14

Sorry, I cannot bring a more useful help yet, as I'm very new to django-cms at this time...

Cheers

Comment: This may be a regression in the very newly released 3.0.4. This issue doesn't appear to be in 3.0.3, try downgrading with `pip install django-cms==3.0.3` and you should be on your way again.